# LIKE command in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

My query:

```
$sel = mysql_query("select * from categorydetails where productname LIKE '%$commonsearch%' ");
```

Where product name = tvs apache rtr:

```
commonsearch = rtr
```

but it's not working

is there a way to use like command when `mysql` column contain more than one word?

Comment: How many records do you have in that column with that search result?

Comment: 10 records as of now

Comment: 10 out of? Because if 50% of your records are the search term then it will be ignored.

Comment: you want only rtr spacific

Comment: no..totally 10 records but that matches search result is only one.

Comment: try this $sel = mysql_query("select * from categorydetails where productname LIKE '%___rtr%' ");

Answer (score 1):

```
$sel = mysql_query("select * from categorydetails where productname LIKE '%___rtr%' ");
```

see the example
   SELECT * FROM `certificates` where csr REGEXP 'tvs'

your query

```
$sel = mysql_query("select * from categorydetails where productname REGEXP '$commonsearch' ");
```

Comment: what if we have `tvs rtr apache` or `rtr tvs apache` ??

Comment: see the answer any where tvs or rtr in a column display the result

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
LIKE '%".$commonsearch."%
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query this is working on single word and multipe string like "test is test"

```
$sel = mysql_query("select * from categorydetails where productname LIKE '%rtr%' or  productname LIKE '%rtr' or productname LIKE 'rtr%' ");
```